# What are the possible reasons for an android app failing to receive BLE notifications from a BLE device it's connected to?

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have posted several questions which are basically the same question over and over again because I honestly can't find the problem.

I need to receive notifications from a BLE device on a particular characteristic. I use the BGX Silicon Labs Bluetooth kit which is connected to a Processor board that we send and receive data from. The documentation states that two characteristics RX and TX are used for data exchange. Rx for sending and TX for receiving.

[image]

Here is the link as well:https://docs.silabs.com/gecko-os/1/bgx/latest/ble-services

Now I tried following the guide from PunchThrough that helps build a starter BLE app for android. I pretty much did everything they did. Now when I enable notifications for the RX characteristic when sending, the onCharacteristicChanged override function gets called as it should be. But when I send a request using that characteristic and expect a response based on that request sent in the form of a notification. Our team seems to manage fine using the software developed for the Desktop version, the android version I am working on however seems to succeed only in Writing data but not receiving. My question is simple, why does the onCharacteristicChanged function never get called when I enable notifications on the Tx characteristic?

The code has a queuing mechanism, and it writes to the descriptor and has notifications enabled on the TX characteristic but I get nothing, nothing at all. I can provide parts of the code if you wish but first I wanted to discuss what possible reason notifications are not received.

Comment: Shouldn't you receive notifications on the TX characteristic after writing to RX? Have you tried using a generic BLE scanner such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to see if notifications work there?

Comment: That's what I'm saying, I receive nothing when notifications are enabled on the TX. I do indeed send the request on the RX and I'm supposed to get notifications or at least have the onCharacteristicChanged function get called but it never does. When I instead enable notifications on the RX it does get called. 

I haven't used the app you linked, does it display notifications when received?

Comment: Yes, you can activate notifications by clicking on the multiple downward arrows next to the characteristic after you connected. You can use the app as a way to verify that your BLE device is behaving correctly and your app is indeed the problem

Comment: okay I have the app downloaded an tried sending the request hex code using the RX characteristic, the TX states that notifications are enabled so where exactly would I detect or receive the notifications? Any tutorials for that kind of thing?

Comment: If you have a characteristic that allows reading (downwards arrow) you will see the result appearing below the characteristic. The same happens with received notifications. You can also view the log by swiping right or selecting the three dots in the upper right corner and selecting "Show log"

Comment: I'll see what I can do, basically what is supposed to happen is for example send this request code: 08 00 00 00 20 30 05 11 00 00 00 00 00  one of several, then I get a response code: 04 00 00 00 20 10 78 11 accompanied by the payload. The latter is supposed to be in the form of notifications. I hope it works.